# C++ global class to prevent multiple socket creations

Tags: c++, sockets, extern, libssh2

I have an application that transfers log files from a client machine to a server. Any time a new log file appears, it is transferred via SCP.

Currently after a transfer is complete, the socket and libssh2 handle are destroyed. This creates a lot of unnecessary CPU cycles on both ends considering how quickly the log files are created. So I'm leaning towards applying a keep-alive logic to the socket to mitigate this.

So my question is, what is the best practice to make a global class that maintains a sockets connectivity and runs an asynchronous timer to check for recent transfers. It's been awhile since I've written in C++ but this is what I have in mind:

SCPSendFile.h

```
class SendFile
{
public:
    SendFile();
    ~SendFile();
    bool SCP_Authenticate();
    bool SCP_TransferFile(string File);
    void SCP_CloseSession();
    void AsyncKeepAlive();

private:
    unsigned int LastTransfer;
#ifdef WIN32
    SOCKET Socket;
#else
    int Socket;
#endif
    int SSH;
    LIBSSH2_SESSION *Session = NULL;

};

extern class SCPSendFile SCPSendFile;
```

Would there be a better approach from what I mentioned above? Are global classes okay and is there a better logic to apply for a keep-alive than creating a timer that verifies last upload?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the timer is for.  But in any case, yes, it's a good idea to use a single libssh2 session for all the transfers.

Comment: it is better to ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com